# Prepared insert statement in node.js using pg and postgresqlDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prepared-statement, postgis

I'm trying to write a Polygon to my Postgresql DB. Postgis is installed and I tried to execute an example Statement and it's working. So far so good.

Here's my example:

```
INSERT INTO assets VALUES('test', 'test2id', 210, ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(16.0 14.0, 20.0 14.0, 20.0 12.0, 16.0 12.0,16.0 14.0)':: geometry, 4326), 'Crime');
```

So I tried to convert this in a prepared statement and my code looks like this:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
})
const sql = "INSERT INTO assets (title, id, duration, geodata, genre) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);"

const values = [title, crid, duration, poly_string, genre]


pool.query(sql, values, (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    response.status(500).send("Internal Server Error")
    throw error
   }
})
```

The values for the variables are like that:

```
poly_string = "ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(16 14, 20 14, 20 12, 16 12, 16 14)':: geometry, 4326)"
title = "test"
id = "IHSJSKLANSHKLSHJSMSNSD"
duration = 1290
genre = "crime"
```

If I run the code I get the following error:

```
error: parse error - invalid geometry

  length: 147,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: 'XX000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: '"ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry',
```

Thankfull for any help or ideas. :)

Comment: Most likely the problem is that your code is sending the function `ST_Polygon` as part of the WKT Literal, which is invalid. Can you check what exactly (the insert statement) you're sending to the database? cheers

Comment: If I search for the statement in the postgresql.log file I only find this: 
2021-10-21 19:12:55.683 CEST [30640] HINT:  "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
2021-10-21 19:12:55.683 CEST [30640] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO assets (title, id, duration, geodata, genre) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);

When I try the complete sql statement I created in the example above it works and the entry is created. 

Is that the right way to see the insert statement? 

Allready thanks for your help :)

Comment: You could maybe insert the coordinates as a string and create a trigger in the database to handle the PostGIS function part. I usually use sqlalchemy/geo alchemy for these things however I am not sure if something similar exists in node. https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/everything-you-need-know-about-postgresql-triggers

Comment: @Oivalf perhaps: `const sql = "INSERT INTO assets (title, id, duration, geodata, genre) VALUES($1, $2, $3, ST_Polygon($4,4326), $5);"`? and removing the function from the WKT literal `poly_string = "'LINESTRING(16 14, 20 14, 20 12, 16 12, 16 14)'"`

Comment: Hey JimJones, I took your code snippet but it still was not working for me. 
So I edited my sql query to the following and now it works for me: 
"INSERT INTO assets (title, id, duration, geodata, genre) VALUES($1, $2, $3, ST_GeomFromText($4,4326), $5);"
Seemed like the ST_Polygon function wasn't working and the ST_GeomFromText() made it work. 
@TimothyDalton, I didn't tried to create a trigger yet, but thanks for your idea. Think that idea should work too. 

Anyway thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Hy Oivalf, I have same case, but on my case is for query Update, here my example query

```
const updatePole =
'UPDATE public."Pole" SET geom = $1, status = $2, WHERE id = $3'
```

when I working on form data on table It's work well, but when I change on maps it's not work, and make data value to be `null`. I was try using this code

```
const updatePole =
'UPDATE public."Pole" SET geom = ST_AsGeoJSON($1,4326::integer), status = $2, WHERE id = $3'
```

and it's working for me.